# Cut on both characters and field

Tags: shell, text-processing, cut

I have a record like :

```
2011-05-29 17:51:34 => 'HS|CMGC|RN431|CI13950|CH7-4a37-afe2-acabfc9d262d|DA110529|TI175133|'
```

I want my final output to be something like:

```
2011-05-29 17:51:34  CI13950
```

I can get each part using cut like this:

```
$ cut -c 1-19
2011-05-29 17:51:34
$ cut -d  '|' -f 4
CI13950
```

I am unable combine the two as:

```
$ cut -c 1-19 -d  '|' -f 4
cut: only one type of list may be specified
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut does its job once. You can run something through `cut` twice to pare it down even further, but it sounds like you need to use something like [`awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14224/cut-on-both-characters-and-field/14242#14242), `sed`, or `perl` instead.

Example of running multiple `cut`s:

```
cut -f 2 | cut -c 3-6
```

Example using `perl` that will work on your data line:

```
perl -pne "s/=> '([^|]+\|){3}([^|]+)/\2/g"
```

Here is a `sed` version from Fred in the comments:

```
sed -re "s/=> ([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*).*/\2/"
```

Comment: sorry mate , but your reply looks clipped out ..

Comment: **Ya it got `cut` :)** I accidentally hit save while I was still testing code in a terminal.

Comment: The same thing using sed: `sed -re "s/ => ([^|]*\|){3}([^|]*).*/  \2/"`

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{split($NF,x,"|"); print $1, $2, x[4]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks [oddly familiar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318671/135943), although I see this actually came first.

The simplest, most readable approach I see is using Awk like so:

```
awk -F'|' '{print substr($0,1,19), $4}' text.txt
```

This is *exactly* equivalent to your attempted command <s>`cut -c 1-19 -d  '|' -f 4`</s>, except that it's working code.  ;)