# Return the first few columns, omit everything after it until a delimiter, and add the rest?

Tags: text-processing, awk, cut

The input is a file (text.txt) containing the following lines of text (all whitespaces are space characters):

```
2016-10-24 10:25:48.939279-0400 0x63a55    Info        0x0                  1416   backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Found 2735 files (298.6 MB) needing backup
2016-10-24 10:25:48.954707-0400 0x63a55    Info        0x0                  1416   backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] 6.08 GB required (including padding), 1.2 TB available
2016-10-24 10:27:56.721350-0400 0x63a55    Info        0x0                  1416   backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied 3128 items (283.1 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5756.
2016-10-24 10:27:59.652854-0400 0x63a55    Info        0x0                  1416   backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Created new backup: 2016-10-24-102758
2016-10-24 10:27:59.638560-0400 0x64abb    Error       0x0                  52     UserEventAgent: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] Failed to send message because the port couldn't be created.
2016-10-24 10:28:00.545654-0400 0x63a55    Error       0x0                  1416   backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] Could not back up OS X Recovery to /Volumes/BackupA/Backups.backupdb: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-69830 "Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk}
```

From the above example I want to produce **only** the date / time stamp followed by all the text after the last bracket delimiter.

This is what I want from the above example:

```
2016-10-24 10:25:48 Found 2735 files (298.6 MB) needing backup
2016-10-24 10:25:48 6.08 GB required (including padding), 1.2 TB available
2016-10-24 10:27:56 Copied 3128 items (283.1 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5756.
2016-10-24 10:27:59 Created new backup: 2016-10-24-102758
2016-10-24 10:27:59 Failed to send message because the port couldn't be created.
2016-10-24 10:28:00 Could not back up OS X Recovery to /Volumes/BackupA/Backups.backupdb: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-69830 "Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk}
```

I can use **cut**, but it only gets stuff after the delimiter.

For example this:

```
cat ~/Desktop/test.txt | grep TimeMachine | rev | cut -d']' -f1 | rev
```

... omits the time stamp:

```
Found 2735 files (298.6 MB) needing backup
6.08 GB required (including padding), 1.2 TB available
Copied 3128 items (283.1 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5756.
Created new backup: 2016-10-24-102758
Failed to send message because the port couldn't be created.
Could not back up OS X Recovery to /Volumes/BackupA/Backups.backupdb: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-69830 "Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk}
```

I can use this,

```
cat ~/Desktop/test.txt | grep TimeMachine | cut -c 1-19,140-
```

... but variable column locations are a problem (notice the last two lines):

```
2016-10-24 10:25:48 Found 2735 files (298.6 MB) needing backup
2016-10-24 10:25:48 6.08 GB required (including padding), 1.2 TB available
2016-10-24 10:27:56 Copied 3128 items (283.1 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5756.
2016-10-24 10:27:59 Created new backup: 2016-10-24-102758
2016-10-24 10:27:59ogError] Failed to send message because the port couldn't be created.
2016-10-24 10:28:00] Could not back up OS X Recovery to /Volumes/BackupA/Backups.backupdb: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-69830 "Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk}
```

I have a feeling there is no way to use **cut** to do what I want, because I want to combine the -c option with the -d option, and I can't figure that out. Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your exact question, this is not a good fit for using `cut` for the following reasons:

1. There are multiple delimiters.
2. There may be a variable number of fields.

---

## Using Awk:

```
awk -F']' '{print substr($0,1,19), $NF}' text.txt
```

## Using Sed:

```
sed 's/^\(....-..-.. ..:..:..\).*\]\([^]]*\)$/\1 \2/' text.txt
```

---

I would favor the Awk method.

Comment: I had been doing backflips trying to get `cut` to work. `awk` is the way to go.

Comment: @MikeGalatean, yep.  :)  If this solved your question, don't forget you can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9]*\).[0-9 \-]*[a-z0-9]x[0-9a-z]*[ ]*[a-zA-Z]*[ ]*[0-9x]*[0-9 ]*/\1 /'
```

EDIT: the sed is using lazy pattern matching;

- anything within brackets () is printed out in \1
- anything else matched is disregarded
- anything after is left untouched

Comment: post edited to add explination

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^.]+).*\](.*)/\1\2/' ip.txt 
2016-10-24 10:25:48 Found 2735 files (298.6 MB) needing backup
2016-10-24 10:25:48 6.08 GB required (including padding), 1.2 TB available
2016-10-24 10:27:56 Copied 3128 items (283.1 MB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 5756.
2016-10-24 10:27:59 Created new backup: 2016-10-24-102758
2016-10-24 10:27:59 Failed to send message because the port couldn't be created.
2016-10-24 10:28:00 Could not back up OS X Recovery to /Volumes/BackupA/Backups.backupdb: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-69830 "Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get info for unmounted Recovery partition (error -69830): This operation requires an unmounted disk}
```

- `^([^.]+)` capture all non`.` characters from start of line
- `.*\]` ignore everything up to last `]` in the line
- `(.*)` capture remaining characters
- `\1\2` first and second captured groups
- Note: Some `sed` versions use `-r` instead of `-E` for extended regex option

  - `sed 's/^\([^.]\+\).*\]\(.*\)/\1\2/'` if extended regex option is not available